# Не вставляется картинка в БД

Tags: delphi, база-данных, firebird

Есть код для вставки изображения в БД:

```
procedure TFMain.SQL_Service(ASwitch: integer; ASql: string);
{ASwitch
    0 - select
    1 - update}
begin
  ibqEmpty1.close;
  ibqEmpty1.SQL.Clear;
  ibqEmpty1.SQL.Text := ASql;
  case ASwitch of
0:
  begin
    ibqEmpty1.Open;
    ibqEmpty1.FetchAll;
    ibqEmpty1.First;
  end;
1:
  begin
    ibqEmpty1.ExecSQL;
    ibtrMain.CommitRetaining;
  end;
  end;
end;
```

и

```
procedure TFMain.sbAddImageClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OpenPictureDialog1.Title := C_save_image;
  OpenPictureDialog1.Filter := 'Image files (*.jpg)|*.jpg| Image files (*.png)|*.png| Image files (*.bmp)|*.bmp';
  if OpenPictureDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    SQL_Service(1, 'insert into IMAGES (ID, ID_MAIN, IMAGE) values (GEN_ID(GEN_ID_IMAGES, 1), 1234, :IMAGE)');
    ibqEmpty1.Params.ParamByName('IMAGE').LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName, ftGraphic);
  end
  else ibqEmpty1.Cancel;

end;
```

В БД вставляется все, **кроме картинки** в поле «IMAGE»,
Почему?
Если через *DataSet*, то все работает, но мне нужно через *Query*, среди всех предлагаемых вариантов, мне понравился этот, Но дело в том, что у других (судя по отзывам), он работает.

Comment: Что написано в логах БД после вашей попытки добавить картинку таким образом? Там можно узнать много интересного.

Comment: честно говоря, я о логе БД еще не знал, не заглядывал туда. а где он создается? в директории "Firebird" - это "firebird.log"? Или для этого нужно скачивать доп. ПО на подобе [ссылка] http://www.upscene.com/downloads.php [/ссылка] или посоветуйте программу пожалуйста

Comment: или это проще сделать с http://koder.kz/articles/ib-expert-firebird/ib-expert-firebird-zhurnalizaciya.html

Comment: Вы же сначала вставляете запись, а потом устанавливаете параметр. Т.е. сначала ExecSQL, а потом param.LoadFromFile.

Comment: @Konstantin78: Попробуйте разобраться, почему параметр не находится. Может быть надо его задать более явно (указав тип, размер и т.п.)

Comment: да, наверное "Yura Ivanov" прав, я сначало должен присвоить параметр, а потом конечно выпонить запрос. Просто для картинки, получилось не удачное расположение процедуры "SQL_Service", просто у меня до этого не было запроса с параметром, и все работало.

Comment: да все верно, сначало параметр, потом выполнение. Только вместо значения "ftGraphic", нужно установить "**ftblob**", иначе на строке "ibqEmpty1.ExecSQL;" вылетает ошибка: "*...class EIBClientError with message 'Unsupported feature*'" Я еще **не** понял почему? Или это из-за **типа поля в БД: - BLOB**, а не графики, я ведь всетаки в БД вставляю. **А можно ли каким-нибудь образом** "*ibqEmpty1.Params.ParamByName('IMAGE').LoadFromFile(OpenPictureDialog1.FileName, ftblob)*" вставить в *ibqEmpty1.SQL.Text := 'insert into IMAGES (ID, ID_MAIN, IMAGE) values (GEN_ID(GEN_ID_IMAGES, 1), :ii, :IMAGE)'*??

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте ка то так:

```
TBlobField(ibqEmpty1.FieldByName('IMAGE')).LoadFromFile(T);
```

Comment: спасибо, но ответ я нашел еще *24 июл в 14:04*